# How to create user defined base type and inherit later to make another user defined type in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

I'm trying to make query converter from oracle to postgres.
There's a TREAT in oracle function which converts input expr to declared type (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/TREAT.html#GUID-037C0CD3-C256-4A02-80E0-C6F15147C5BF) and i'm trying to find similar query corresponding to this function. So I tried the example query in the document i linked.
and in order to see the result of the example I had to make new data type something like this.

```
CREATE TYPE person_t AS OBJECT (name VARCHAR2(100), ssn NUMBER) NOT FINAL;
CREATE TYPE employee_t UNDER person_t(department_id NUMBER, salary NUMBER) NOT FINAL;
```

and then inserted some datas in the table.

```
INSERT INTO persons VALUES (person_t('Bob', 1234));
INSERT INTO persons VALUES (employee_t('Joe', 32456, 12, 100000));
INSERT INTO persons VALUES (
   part_time_emp_t('Tim', 5678, 13, 1000, 20));
```

and of course i created table persons before, and used treat function.

```
SELECT name, TREAT(VALUE(p) AS employee_t).salary salary 
   FROM persons p;
```

which shows this [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xe9XW.png).

and I'm curious if i can do the same thing or similar this in postgres as i'm trying to make as same query as possible from oracle to postgres.

I know that postgres also have create type clause but is there a way to create type as base type just like oracle create type ... not final does?
if not is there a way to do this kida thing?

Comment: There is no inheritance for types in Postgres

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equivalent to type subclassing in PostgreSQL. There are related functionalities:

- `TREAT` looks like `CAST`. I don't really see the difference to a type cast.
- There is [table inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html).

However, you will reap what you get from using non-standard features: you will have to rewrite. I recommend getting rid of using user-defined types in general. Let your `persons` table have all attributes for every conceivable sub-type and add a `person_type` column.